# How to use style.css in extend pages?

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2

I've a problem with style in my app. I've put my style.css file into static folder but when put the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
```

My main page (body2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

HERE IS BOOTSTRAP CDN

**<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">**
</head>

<header>
HERE IS MY NAVBAR CODE
</header>

<style>
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
</style>

<body>
{% block content %}
HERE IS MY PAGE WHICH I EXTEND
{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

And page which I'd like to extend

```
    {% extends "body2.html" %}
    {% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}
    {% block content %}


HERE IS LOTS OF CODE :)    

    {% endblock %}
```

The problem is that I don't see my background

style.css

```
    body, html {
    height: 200%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(90deg, #16222A 10%, #3A6073 90%); /* W3C */

}
```

Comment: if it's a CDN shouldn't you be able to use absolute links? O.o

Answer (score 1):

You are linking an external stylesheet, you should not put that link in a style tag.
Also a good practice is to load external files in the head, so the style of the elements is known before loading the page.